"hōc enim ūnō modō...scelus" or "hoc enim ūnō modō...scelus" ? (Ritchie's Fabulae faciles, §20)
I read in Ritchie's Fabulae faciles ([Hercules, §20], macrons are mine):

Vbi Herculēs fīnem fēcit, Pȳthia prīmō tacēbat; tandem tamen iussit
eum ad urbem Tīryntha īre et Eurysthēī rēgis omnia imperāta facere.
Herculēs ubi hæc audīuit, ad urbem illam contendit et Eurysthēō rēgī
sē in seruitūtem trādidit. Duodecim annōs crūdēlissimō Eurystheō
seruiēbat et duodecim labōrēs, quōs ille imperāuerat, cōnfēcit; hōc
enim ūnō modō tantum scelus expiārī potuit.

My translation:

When Hercules had finished speaking, the Pythia at first remained
silent; at last, however, she ordered him to go to Tirynthe and obey
all the orders of King Eurystheus. When Hercules heard these words, he
hurried to Tirynthe and made himself Eurystheus' slave. For twelve
years he served the cruel Eurystheus, carrying out the twelve labors
he had been ordered to perform; it was the only way to atone for his crime.

I understand the clause "hōc enim ūnō modō tantum scelus expiārī potuit" in two ways:

either hōc is a singular ablative determining ūnō modō (... to perform; it was the only way to atone for his crime)
either hoc is a nominative determining scelus (...to perform as the only way to atone for this crime).

Which interpretation do you think is better?

Both readings are plausible and the essential message is the same, so the choice of interpretation might not even show up in a translation.
The distinction is there, but my first point is to encourage you to think whether making it is actually worthwhile.
Having said that, the former interpretation is better in my opinion.
The pronoun hoc tends to point to the most recent thing mentioned, and the narration has just covered the ways (modi) of atonement.
The discussion of the crime (scelus) is further back, so I find it unlikely that hoc refers to scelus unless there was a specific habit of using the phrase hoc scelus before the passage you quote.
Also, if hoc were to refer to scelus, the one way (unus modus) is left unspecific.
I would read the ending along these lines: "the crime could be atoned for in only one way".
The statement would be about the uniqueness of the way, not that it was what was just listed.
This further underlines the notion that hoc should point to the preceding description of the way.

I think hōc here goes with modo. I would translate as "for in this way alone could such a deed be atoned for."
However, I guess it could go with scelus also, like Cicero's "hoc tantum facinus" in In Verrem 2.1.90.3.
